# How do I prevent a DataGridTemplateColumn from going into edit-mode based on some condition?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn, editmode

I have a DataGridTemplateColumn that is editable.  I only want the user to be able to edit the content of a cell in this column if the business object satisfies some criterion.  Suppose my business object implements INotifyPropertyChanged and has three properties: *Name*, *Department*, and *Sales*.  *Name* and *Department* are strings, and *Sales* is a double.

I want the user to be able to edit the *Sales* value only if *Department* equals "Retail".  Here's a datagrid I might use to do this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyTypeCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneTime}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Department" Binding="{Binding Path=Department, Mode=OneTime}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sales">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Sales, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="{Binding Path={StaticResource ResourceKey=IsRetail}}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Sales, Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="{Binding Path={StaticResource ResourceKey=IsNotRetail}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Sales, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="{Binding Path={StaticResource ResourceKey=IsRetail}}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Sales, Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="{Binding Path={StaticResource ResourceKey=IsNotRetail}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I'm using a stack panel with two Text elements.  I use a binding in the Visibility of the Text elements to toggle Text elements.  If I have a row with a *Department* value that is not "Retail", I display a TextBlock in the *Sales* column whether the cell is in display mode or edit mode.

This seems like a clumsy solution to me.  Is there some way I can prevent these types of cells from entering edit mode entirely?  I only want to allow edit mode in the case that the *Department* is "Retail".  Is this possible?

Edit: Adding code.

@Rachel.  Thank you for your help.  I want to paste in all of my datagrid XAML code to make sure I have everything right.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}">

    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Sales}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Department" Binding="{Binding Path=Department, Mode=OneTime}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneTime}" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="salesControl">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sales}" />
                    </ContentControl>

                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Department}" Value="Retail">
                            <Setter TargetName="salesControl" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sales}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I've almost got this where I want it.  When I click on a `Sales` value in a `Retail` row, a TextBox appears but it doesn't have a value in it (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssrgi.png)).  I'm not sure why it doesn't have a value because the TextBox in the TextBoxTemplate specifies a binding.  Do you know why this is?

Edit: I noticed one other problem with this solution, I can't actually edit the value in the Sales column.  If I try, the value reverts to the original pre-edit value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `DataTrigger` which toggles the value of a property like `TextBox.IsReadOnly` based on if the Department is equal to "Retail" or not

```
<Style ...>
    <!-- Set Default -->
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Department}" Value="Retail">
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you don't need any other editing in your DataGrid, it would be easiest to set `IsReadOnly="True"` on your `DataGrid` to disable editing entirely, and set this style on the `TextBox` in your `DataGridTemplateColumn`. This would get rid of a lot of your extra XAML code, like `IsReadOnly="True"`

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyTypeCollection}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          IsReadOnly="True">

    <!-- This could also go in Window.Resources, UserControl.Resources, etc -->
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="SalesTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <!-- Set Default -->
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Department}" Value="Retail">
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Department" Binding="{Binding Path=Department}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sales">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Sales}" 
                             Style="{StaticResource SalesTextBoxStyle}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If you do need the default DataGrid editing functionality, you could still use the same thing, but you'd only need a single `TextBox`/`TextBlock` in your `DataTemplate` instead of the `StackPanel` and multiple objects.

And if you really want it to display an actual `TextBlock` instead of a `TextBox` when the user doesn't have the ability to edit, you can use a `ContentControl` and toggle it's `ContentTemplate` property with a `DataTrigger`

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.Resources>

...

<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl x:Name="salesControl" Content="{Binding Sales}" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Department}" Value="Retail">
                    <Setter TargetName="salesControl" 
                            Property="ContentTemplate" 
                            Value="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I'm getting some errors with your third code block.  On the line `<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sales" Style="{StaticResource SalesCellTemplate}" />`, I get an error on the `Style` attribute that says "'Style' was not found on type 'DataGridTemplateColumn'".  If I comment out that line, I get an error on the line `<Setter Property="CellTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" />` that says "Property 'CellTemplate' was not found on type 'DataGridCell'".  Did I copy your code incorrectly?

Comment: @user2023861 Sorry, I wrote that without a compiler to double-check the syntax. See my updated answer for a working code sample

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  I almost have what I want.  I have one small problem: the TextBox that appears during edit-mode is not initially loaded with the `Sales` value.  I wanted to post all of my datagrid xaml code, so I put in an edit to my original post.  Is something wrong with my binding?  How can I have the TextBox display the `Sales` value?

Comment: @user2023861 Change the binding in your `TextBoxTemplate` from `{Binding Path=Sales}` to just `{Binding }`. The DataContext of the ContentControl should already be the `Sales` property, so the current syntax is trying to access `Sales.Sales`, which doesn't exist

Comment: I set the Binding to `{Binding }` like you said, but that didn't seem to do it.  I put a simple converter in the binding so that I could see what is getting bound, and it turns out if I set the binding path to `Path=.`, the Converter value is of type `TextBlock`.  I would have guessed that it was of type `RowType` (which is my business object).  I could use the `Text` property of the TextBox, but when the user submits an edit, I have no way of setting the `Sales` value in the appropriate RowType.

Comment: @user2023861 Ahh I forgot you need to specify a `Path` for a TwoWay binding, so you are correct, you need to bind `TextBox.Text` to `{Binding Path=.}` instead of `{Binding }` :) The `DataContext` for your `DataGridRow` and `DataGridCell` should be your data object, and the `DataContext` for your `TextBox` should be the `Sales` property

Comment: I got it to work!  Thanks!  I posted my code as another answer.  Don't worry, I gave you the check mark :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also subscribe to the `BeginningEdit` event of the DataGrid and then add a simple check in the code-behind.

In the XAML:

```
<DataGrid BeginningEdit="DataGrid_BeginningEdit" />
```

Example code:

```
private void DataGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
{
    RowViewModel VM = (RowViewModel)((DataGrid)sender).SelectedItem;

    if (!VM.IsRetail) { e.Cancel = true; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work using this code.  I don't totally understand it, but it works as I want it to work.  Thanks Rachel!

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}">

    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, StringFormat=c0}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Department" Binding="{Binding Path=Department, Mode=OneTime}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneTime}" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sales">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="salesControl" DataContext="{Binding Path=.}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Sales, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=c0}" />
                    </ContentControl>

                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Department}" Value="Retail">
                            <Setter TargetName="salesControl" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sales, StringFormat=c0}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```